# how to release the Views?

Tags: ios, uiview, view, release

i create views in viewDidLoad,such as

```
UIScrollView* scrollViewright = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,400,768)];
[scrollViewright setContentSize:CGSizeMake(400,1000)];
[self.view addSubview:scrollViewright];
```

so,how can i release them?

i use [scrollViewright release]; in '- (void)dealloc'  and self.scrollViewright = nil in '-(void)viewDidUnload',both of them tell me wrong ,so can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have two kinds of release that can be done:

```
UIScrollView* scrollViewright = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,400,768)];
[scrollViewright setContentSize:CGSizeMake(400,1000)];
[self.view addSubview:scrollViewright];
[scrollViewright release];
```

And the next one, when you want to remove the scrollView from the main view:

```
[scrollViewright removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `addSubview:` will retain `scrollViewright`, you can release it right after `addSubview:` or add an `autorelease` message when you first declare it:

```
UIScrollView* scrollViewright = [[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,400,768)] autorelease];
```

Note that `scrollViewright` is a local variable inside `viewDidLoad`so it is unavailable outside that method.